# Maintaining structure with Nginx and multiple NodeJS applications

Tags: ajax, node.js, nginx

I'm trying to host multiple Node JS servers proxied through Nginx, which is working correctly. One server is hosted at '/', with another hosted at, for example, '/one'. The relevant Nginx config for this setup is below.

> ```
> upstream host_com {
>   server 127.0.0.1:3000;
>   keepalive 8;
> }
> upstream one_host_com {
>   server 127.0.0.1:3010;
>   keepalive 8;
> }
> server {
>   listen 80;
>   access_log /var/log/nginx/host.log;
>   location / {
>     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
>     proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
>     proxy_pass http://host_com/;
>     proxy_redirect off;
>   }
>   location /one {
>     rewrite ^(/one)+/(.*)$ /$2 break;
>     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>     proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host; #$http_host;
>     proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
>     proxy_pass http://one_host_com/;
>     proxy_redirect off;
>   }
> ```
>
> }

However, when I do an AJAX call from the '/one' testbed, like below:

> $.getJSON( '/get_stuff', function(data) { .. });

The post goes to '/get_stuff' when I want it to go to '/one/get_stuff'. How can I get Nginx to direct to NodeJS but still maintain the location? Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the leading slash in your JavaScript, e.g. `$.getJSON( 'get_stuff', function(data) { .. });`. By including the leading slash you are asking for a path at the root of the domain but I think you want the path relative to the url you are presently at.

Comment: Without the slash, running the call as you have it, still has the request URL as "http://(ip)/get_stuff" and still isn't calling to the 'one' testbed.

Comment: After some more tinkering, I found your step did help, but I also needed to set the base in the HTML, `<base href="one/">`. Once that was done relative URL's work correctly for AJAX, so long as I have my rewrite in the Nginx config.

Comment: More clarification; setting the base is not actually necessary. The issue was that I was accessing `http://(ip)/one` without a trailing slash. With the trailing slash, the relative url works fine. Looks like I just need to catch that in my Nginx config.